# Selecting Top 5 records of each group based on date (Access/SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to select 5 records from each Startup System ([SU SYS-TO DATE].STARTUP_SYS) based off  the most recent or future CURRTARGETCOMPDATE.
I believe I will need to add a subquery to my SQL query, but I am having a hard time figuring out how:

```
SELECT Friday_Meeting.ID, [SU SYS-TO DATE].STARTUP_SYS, [SU SYS-TO DATE].[FORECAST DATE], TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.PUNCHITEM_KEY, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.ORIGINATOR_NAME, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.TAG_NO, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.ENTRYDATE, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.FIELD_ENGINEER, [ITEM_DESCRIPTION1] & " " & [ITEM_DESCRIPTION2] & " " & [TAG_NO] & " " & " " & [CRECORD] AS Description, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.PRIORITY_CODE, [REMARKS1] & " " & [REMARKS2] AS Remarks, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.RESTRAINTS, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.SUPERINTENDENT, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.PIDISCIPLINE, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.CURRTARGETCOMPDATE, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.ORIGTARGETCOMPDATE, TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.CRECORD
FROM Friday_Meeting LEFT JOIN ([SU SYS-TO DATE] LEFT JOIN TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM ON [SU SYS-TO DATE].STARTUP_SYS = TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.STARTUP_SYS) ON Friday_Meeting.[SU SYS] = [SU SYS-TO DATE].STARTUP_SYS
WHERE ((([SU SYS-TO DATE].STARTUP_SYS)="MVE-L-01" Or ([SU SYS-TO DATE].STARTUP_SYS)="LVE-A-01" Or ([SU SYS-TO DATE].STARTUP_SYS)="GRE-A-01or LVE-B-03" Or ([SU SYS-TO DATE].STARTUP_SYS)="LVE-B-07" Or ([SU SYS-TO DATE].STARTUP_SYS)="CHW-B-01") AND ((TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.PRIORITY_CODE)="A") AND ((TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.CURRTARGETCOMPDATE)>=[FORECAST DATE]-14) AND ((TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.RECORD_CLOSURE) Is Null) AND ((TEAMWORKS_24590_TOPUNCHITEM.DELETED)="N"))
ORDER BY Friday_Meeting.ID;
```

I truly appreciate any help and guidance!

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

Comment: in the future use http://www.sql-format.com/